# DocumentDb query with DateTime

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have object: (it's only part!)

```
class Flyer { public DateTime? ValidTo {get;set;} }
```

And in DocumentDb it looks this way:

```
"ValidTo": "2016-11-05T22:59:00Z"
```

And if in C# backend I doing this:

```
var query = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<FlyerDocument>(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseName, CollectionName))
                .Where(
                    doc =>
                        doc.Type == DocumentType.Flyer &&
                        doc.Entity.ValidTo != null && doc.Entity.ValidTo >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7))
                .AsDocumentQuery();

            var results = new List<FlyerDocument>();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<FlyerDocument>());
            }
```

And it 
`doc.Entity.ValidTo >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7)`
throws `InvalidOperationException`

How to overcome it?

@EDIT:
Exception message is `nullable object must have a value`
@EDIT 2:
There are some documents in DB that do not have this field.

Comment: have more info? whats the message of the InvalidOperationException?

Comment: I can't repro it on my side with documentdefinition `var documentDefinition = new FlyerDocument
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Type = DocumentType.Flyer,
                Entity = new Entity
                {
                    ValidTo = DateTime.UtcNow
                }

            };` . If it is possible, please share how to create document.